# How do I use a custom loader in Webpack 2?

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-2

I'm using Webpack 2. I wrote a custom loader for this project and put it in `./webpack-tools/loaders/my-custom-loader.js`. The loader looks like this:

```
module.exports = function myCustomLoader(input) {
    // Logic for my custom loader
    return stringWithTransformedJS;
};
```

I've tried to configure my `webpack.config.json` to use this custom loader:

```
// ...
resolveLoader: {
  modulesDirectories: ['./webpack-tools/loaders'],
  extensions: ['.js']
},
module: {
  loaders: [
    // ...
    {
      test: /\.less$/,
      loader: 'myCustomLoader!less'
    },
    // ...
  ]
},
// ...
```

When I try to build my project, I get the following error (scrubbed to remove identifying information about my project):

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:373:25)
    at Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (/home/kevin/Programming/my-project/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:154:7)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/kevin/Programming/my-project/src/a-file-that-imports-a-LESS-file.js:1:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    // remainder of stack trace removed for conciseness
```

(I must admit that I find this error message very unhelpful. The message "SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL" doesn't give me any clue what's wrong, and my custom loader doesn't appear anywhere in the full trace..)

I've tried several different ways of referencing my custom loader in `webpack.config.js`, including:

```
resolveLoader: {
  alias: {
    myCustomLoader: require.resolve(path.join(__dirname, './webpack-tools/loaders/my-custom-loader.js'))
  }
},
```

And:

```
module: {
  loaders: [
    // ...
    {
      test: /\.less$/,
      loader: './webpack-tools/loaders/my-custom-loader.js!less'
    },
    // ...
  ]
},
```

But I get the same error regardless of which configuration I use.

How do I correctly include my custom loader in my Webpack 2 project?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Unfortunately, I did not. :(

Comment: How about for Webpack 3?